# Role based authentication feed back to user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, role-based

I am using role based Authentication for some of the features in my ASP.NET MVC application by implementing

```
<Authorize(Roles:="Administrator")> _
 Function AdminPage() As ActionResult
    Return View()
  End Function
```

If the user is not logged in as Administrator this will redirect the user to login page but there is no feed back why it did that. So I want to display a message like "You must be administrator to access this feature."

I am looking for a clean way to do this.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily achieve this by writing a custom authorize attribute:

```
Public Class CustomAuthorizeAttribute
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute
    Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
        MyBase.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)
        filterContext.Controller.TempData("message") = String.Format("You need to be {0} to access this resource", Me.Roles)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then decorate the controller action with this custom attribute:

```
<CustomAuthorize(Roles := "Administrator")> _
Public Function AdminPage() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

And somewhere on your Logon View:

```
<div><%: TempData("message") %></div>
```